# Setup Project, Custom Actions and Windows 7 Problems

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a big problem with my Project and the setup that i made for it.
My application, is in VS2005 and it installs a MDF file (SqlExpress 2005) in ApplicationData folder in Windows 7.

The first problem I got was when the installer puts the MDF and LDF in the `ApplicationData\MyApplication` folder, the permissions are wrong and then my application can't access the files to attach to SQL Express.

So what I made was a custom action that gives Everyone permissions (I know.. this isn't very good). OK, so far my application works with that.

The second problem I face is that if the user is not the default Administrator account, when he executes the msi file, the MSI shows a 2869 error when it tries to run the custom action. With this problem I must force the user to execute the setup.exe and not the MSI file. Or if the user executes the MSI file, then some way do the correct setup.

I read something about the NoImpersonate and NoImpersonate.js script in the PostBuildEvent:

```
cscript.exe "$(ProjectDir)NoImpersonate.js" "$(BuiltOuputPath)"
```

But when I do this, some folders or error logs in my application are not created.

I hope that I gave all the information. I need to resolve this problem and I don't know how I can do it.

**EDIT:**

I wrote the wrong directory. It's not ApplicationData, the directory is ProgramData. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

> The first problem i got was when the
>   installer puts the mdf and ldf in the
>   ApplicationData\MyApplication folder,
>   the permissions are wrong

Are you using the user Application Data folder or the all users folder? Also, what permissions do you need?

If you use the per-user folder, you shouldn't need to set any permissions. If you are using the all users folder, your application should always run with Administrator privileges so it can write in that location.

> The second problem i face is that if
>   the user, is not the default
>   administrator account, then the user
>   execute, the msi file, then the msi
>   performs a 2869 error when it try's to
>   make the custom action.

This happens because the custom action fails. Your approach is incorrect, you shouldn't need to set custom permissions for Application Data folder. So you don't need any custom actions.

Comment: The ApplicationData folder doesn't have a user or a all users folder.. i think you are confused with the c:\Users\...\ApplicationData. The folder i mean is the C:\ApplicationData folder

Comment: I'm sorry.. i put the wrong directory in my question, the directory is ProgramData.

Comment: Program Data is "All Users\Application Data" on Vista and Windows 7. So I maintain my suggestion: your application should always run with Administrator privileges so it can write in that folder. However, if you really want to use the custom action, you need to make it run without impersonation. This is not really possible with Visual Studio, but it can easily be done with other setup authoring tools.

Comment: You mean something like Installshield?

Comment: Yes, something like that but cheaper. For example, you can use WiX which is free.

Comment: About the ProgramData folder.. in windows 7 is not in AllUsers\ApplicationData.. the folder ProgramData is in the root and is a hidden folder.. i dont understand what you mean with the AllUsers\ApplicationData

Comment: All Users\Application Data was on XP. It became ProgramData in Vista.